# Browserify Bundle Error when Running in Karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, angular2-testing, isparta

When I run Karma with this configuration:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',        // TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new exports.Map()')
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js', // 'Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators'
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',        // Zone.js dependencies (Zone undefined)
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      'app/**/*.spec.ts',
      {pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map', included: false, served: true}, // 404 on the same
      {pattern: 'www/build/**/*.html', included: false},
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules/angular2/**/*_spec.js',
      'node_modules/ionic-angular/**/*spec*'
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.ts': ['browserify']
    },

    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [
        ['browserify-istanbul', {
          instrumenter: require('isparta'),
          ignore: ['**/*.spec.ts','**/*.d.ts', '**/index.ts', '**/mocks.ts', '**/*.mock.ts'],
        }]
      ],
      plugin: [
        ['tsify']
      ]
    },

    // options on how to report coverage:
    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        {type: 'text'},
        {type: 'lcov', dir: 'coverage', subdir: '.'}
      ]
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],

    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'junitout', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'karma-results.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // GOTCHA -- Karma proxies _everything_ through base first..
    //           Also any files you want to serve need to be in the files array above with serverd: true
    proxies: {
      '/build': '/base/www/build'
    },

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [
      'Chrome',
    ],

    // https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/issues/82
    // try increasing this value if you see the error "Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 30000 ms."
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000
  });

  if (process.env.TRAVIS || process.env.CIRCLECI) {
    config.browsers = ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'];
  }
};
```

I keep getting the following error:

> [16:31:32] Using gulpfile
>   C:\P4Space\Labs\MainRls\Labs\Web\PatientPortal\gulp\karma\gulpfile.ts
>   [16:31:32] Starting 'unit-test'... [16:31:32] Starting
>   'clean:build:all'... [16:31:32] Finished 'clean:build:all' after 15 ms
>   [16:31:32] Starting 'html'... [16:31:32] Finished 'html' after 26 ms
>   [16:31:32] Starting 'karma'... 21 08 2016 16:31:37.431:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: bundle error 21 08 2016 16:31:37.432:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: TypeScript error:
>   C:/P4Space/Labs/MainRls/Labs/Web/PatientPortal/node_modules/@angular/core/src/
>   application_ref.d.ts(79,88): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   21 08 2016 16:31:37.438:ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error 21
>   08 2016 16:31:37.439:ERROR [framework.browserify]: TypeScript error:
>   C:/P4Space/Labs/MainRls/Labs/Web/PatientPortal/node_modules/@angular/core/src/
>   application_ref.d.ts(137,42): Error TS2304: Cannot find name
>   'Promise'. 21 08 2016 16:31:37.440:ERROR [framework.browserify]:
>   bundle error 21 08 2016 16:31:37.441:ERROR [framework.browserify]:
>   TypeScript error:
>   C:/P4Space/Labs/MainRls/Labs/Web/PatientPortal/node_modules/@angular/core/src/
>   application_ref.d.ts(196,33): Error TS2304: Cannot find name
>   'Promise'.

I tried adding the files d.ts to the config files section @ karma.config, but it didn't work.